# beautifulsoup get tags after <p> tag after <h3> and <br> tag between <p>

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have the following raw html:

```
<h3>Job Description</h3>
<p>We are recruiting part time or full time cashier, to be based at our restaurant at Fraser Place, Jalan Perak.</p>
<p>Work Day: Monday to Friday<br> Work Hour: 7am-5pm (Full time), 9am-2pm (Part Time) or 10am-2pm (Part Time)</p>
<p>Full time rate at RM1600-RM1800 per month depends on experience, part time rate RM7-RM8/ hour depends on experience.</p>
<hr>
<h3>Working Location </h3>
```

I'm trying to get all text under "Job Descrtion" only excluding `<hr>` tag

I've tried:

```
for header in soup.find_all('h3'):
    para = header.find_next_sibling('p')
```

but only manage to get first `<p>` after "Job desription" and also it will not run on `<br>` tag within `<p>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate your `header` siblings until you match `hr`.

Example:

```
example = """<h3>Job Description</h3>
<p>We are recruiting part time or full time cashier, to be based at our 
restaurant at Fraser Place, Jalan Perak.</p>
<p>Work Day: Monday to Friday**<br>** Work Hour: 7am-5pm (Full time), 9am-2pm 
(Part Time) or 10am-2pm (Part Time)</p>
<p>Full time rate at RM1600-RM1800 per month depends on experience, part time 
rate RM7-RM8/ hour depends on experience.</p>
<hr>
<h3>Working Location </h3>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'html.parser')
for header in soup.find_all('h3'):
    nextNode = header
    while True:
        nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
        if nextNode is None:
            break
        if nextNode.name is not None:
            if nextNode.name == "hr":
                break
            print (nextNode.get_text(strip=True))
```

Outputs:

```
We are recruiting part time or full time cashier, to be based at our 
restaurant at Fraser Place, Jalan Perak.
Work Day: Monday to Friday**** Work Hour: 7am-5pm (Full time), 9am-2pm (Part 
Time) or 10am-2pm (Part Time)
Full time rate at RM1600-RM1800 per month depends on experience, part time 
rate RM7-RM8/ hour depends on experience.
```

Comment: I've switch but now its getting different result from output. Also I've updated my code above as previously i tried to bold `<br>` and `<hr>` tag for readability but ends up submitting wrong syntax